# Listing Apache Derby Active Connections

Tags: database, derby

Is it possible to query Apache Derby for a list of current connections/active sessions?
Any system tables etc?

Answer (score 2):

The SYSCS_DIAG tables will let you get a list of the active transactions, but that's not the same as the list of connections or sessions.

You can get somewhat close to what you want by using the JMX beans to access the Network Server. There's some docs here: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/DerbyJMXQuickStart

If the current JMX beans don't give you everything you need, you can enhance them to provide more information.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, in my opinion. The quick start linked to takes you to a place where the number of active connections is listed.